# adding class active to the selected anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this `jQuery` code to toggle my active class between my anchors but sadly it is not working and it is adding the class active to all the anchors.

```
$(function() {
  $('.categories-list li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

and my anchors looks like that:

```
<a href="/blog/category/motoring+advice+&amp;+tips" class="active">motoring advice &amp; tips</a>
<a href="/blog/category/motoring+news+&amp;+updates" class="active">motoring news &amp; updates</a>
```

The active class repeated on al of them which is not what i am trying to achieve. i tried to edit it to be like that :

```
$(function() {
  $('.categories-list li a[href^="/blog/category/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

but still it didn't work.

```
.categories-list li
```

This is just my `ul` class and my `li`

Comment: what you are getting in `location.pathname`?

Comment: the current url

Comment: Can you share that in `location.pathname` along with little bit more `HTML`?

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector matches all your anchors, use an ID, a more precise selector, or use .eq(x) where x is the index of the node you want.

Answer (score 0):

thats how i solve this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        addActiveClass();

        function addActiveClass() {
          var current = window.location.pathname;
          $('.categories-list-blog li a').each(function() {
            var link = '' + $(this).attr('href');
            if (current == link) {
              $(this).addClass('active');
            }
          });
        }
      });
```